# CAB file API clarification

Tags: delphi, winapi, cab

Since I'm not really seeing any content anywhere that doesn't point back to the original Microsoft documents on this matter, or source code that really doesn't seem to answer the questions I'm having, I thought I might ask a few things here. (Delphi tag is there because that's what my dev environment is on the code I'm making from this)

That said, I had a few questions the API document wasn't answering.  First one: fdi_notify messages.  What is "my responsibility" is in coding these: `fdintCABINET_INFO: fdintPARTIAL_FILE: fdintNEXT_CABINET: fdintENUMERATE:` ?   I'll illustrate what I mean by an example.  For `fdintCLOSE_FILE_INFO`, "my responsibility" is to Close a file related to handle given me, and set the file's date and time according to the data passed in fdi_notify.

I figure I'm missing something since my code isn't handling extracting spanned CAB files...any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You need to link to some background info so that those of us that have no idea what you are talking about can get up to speed

Comment: If you're trying to unpack CAB files there is an open source alternative: http://www.cabextract.org.uk/ The library is licensed under LGPL terms and can be used in commercial applications.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Your example is clear: when you receive `fdintCLOSE_FILE_INFO`, you're supposed to close the file and set it's date and time to the values you received. (I got that just from the content you posted, BTW, since you omitted important info from your question, as David mentioned.) I'm not sure how that can be any more clearly stated.

Comment: @David Heffernan Craig Peterson did, actually.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797921%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for the API description.  As well see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797944%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for the message descriptions in the post above.

Comment: I said, for those us that don't know what you are talking about. You got lucky. I would say Craig deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're more than likely running into is that **FDICopy** only reads the cab you passed in.  It will use `fdintNEXT_CABINET` to get spanned data for any files you extract in response to `fdintCOPY_FILE`, but it only calls `fdintCOPY_FILE` for files that start on that first cab.

To get a directory listing for the entire set, you need to call **FDICopy** in a loop.  Every time you get a `fdintCABINET_INFO` event, save off the `psz1` parameter (next cab name).  When FDICopy returns, check that.  If it's an empty string you're done, if not call FDICopy again with the next cab as the new path.

---

**fdintCABINET_INFO**: The only responsibility for this is returning 0 to continue processing.  You can use the information provided (the path of the next cabinet, next disk, path name, nad set ID), but you don't need to.

**fdintPARTIAL_FILE**: Depending on how you're processing your cabs, you can probably ignore this.  You'll only see it for the second and later images in a set, and it's to tell you that the particular entry is continued from a previous cab.  If you started at the first cab in the set you'll have already seen an `fdintCOPY_FILE` for the file.  If you're processing random .cabs, you won't really be able to use it either, since you won't have the start of the file to extract.

**fdintNEXT_CABINET**: You can use this to prompt the user for a new directory for the next cabinet, but for simple spanning support just return 0 if the passed in filename is valid or -1 if it isn't.  If you return 0 and the cab isn't valid, or is the wrong one, this will get called again.  The easiest approach (if you don't request a new disk/directory), is just to check `pfdin^.fdie`.  If it's **FDIError_None** it's equal the first time being called for the requested cab, so you can return 0.  If it's anything else it's already tried to open the requested cab at least once, so you can return -1 as an error.

**fdintENUMERATE**: I think you can ignore this.  It isn't covered in the documentation, and the two cab libraries I've looked at don't use it.  It may be a leftover from a previous API version.

Comment: This was very useful.  Thanks.  So to extract a spanned file, I would need to start with the beginning entry and then do a loop, call FDICopy, and continue until the file is done or the next CAB file is not found?

Comment: If you want to extract a file that *begins* on a specific cab, you can just call FDICopy once, and it will automatically request the additional cabs using fdintNEXT_CABINET.  You only need to call FDICopy in a loop if you want to enumerate the entire set or extract files that begin on multiple cabs.

Comment: As a concrete example, download Split.cab, .c02, .c03 from http://tpabbrevia.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tpabbrevia/trunk/tests/testfiles/Canterbury/Split/  They contain 14 files, split across the 3 cabs, and some of the files on the first cab continue onto the second.  WinZip only calls FDICopy once, so it shows 7 files;  PowerArchiver calls it in a loop so you'll see all of them.  If you use FDICopy on just Split.cab, it will open Split.c02 to get the data for the two files continued from Split.cab, but won't return files that start on it.